# Flash Player usage

Tags: deanonymization

Just started with Tor yesterday. I understand downloading and using Tor means no longer having Flash Player and the reasons why, BUT...when using online sites like PicMonkey (which I use for my work) I NEED to have Flash Player. Is there something else I can use that will enable me to continue using PicMonkey and still use Tor as well?

Answer (score 1):

Using flashplayer will reveal your real ip-address. This renders Tor useless to you. However, if you truly don't care; you can use a Virtual Machine with a Gateway so that your real ip can't be leaked. If you download both VirtualBox and Whonix from: Virtualbox.org and Whonix.org, you can do this without completely killing your anonymity. (It basically only allows connections to go through the Tor network)