# I have trouble watching some video using the Tor Browser

Tags: plugin, flash

Wanted to watch Colbert from stated but Tor says the plugin is disabled.

Comment: Flash is disabled by default for security reasons. There are ways of enabling it, but even if you did, Tor is usually too slow to reliably watch videos. I suggest you look into a good VPN.

Comment: See also [here](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3931/why-cant-tor-browser-use-adobe-flash-player), and [here](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1843/flash-player-usage), and [here](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3931/why-cant-tor-browser-use-adobe-flash-player).